# MySQL unknown column using subquery

Tags: mysql

I receive an error when i execute this query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT count(cp_projeto_view.id) FROM cp_projeto_view WHERE cp_projeto_view.id_projeto = cp_projeto.id AND cp_projeto_view.id_pessoa = 467 LIMIT 1) AS qtde_visualizacoes
FROM cp_projeto
WHERE qtde_visualizacoes = 0
```

The error is: **#1054 - Unknown column 'qtde_visualizacoes' in 'where clause'**

Why qtde_visualizacoes does not exists?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause (unless you use a subquery).  MySQL has an extension where you can use `having` instead:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(cp_projeto_view.id)
        FROM cp_projeto_view
        WHERE cp_projeto_view.id_projeto = cp_projeto.id AND cp_projeto_view.id_pessoa = 467
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS qtde_visualizacoes
FROM cp_projeto
HAVING qtde_visualizacoes = 0
```

EDIT:

The query that you probably want is more like:

```
select p.*
from cp_projecto p
where not exists (select 1 from cp_projeto_view pv where pv.id_projeto = p.id and pv.id_pessoa = 467)
```

This will return all `cp_projecto`s that have no matching rows in `cp_projeto_view`.  Your original query would only return rows with a single column of `0`s, which doesn't make much sense.  If you want the count, then do:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from cp_projecto p
where not exists (select 1 from cp_projeto_view pv where pv.id_projeto = p.id and pv.id_pessoa = 467)
```

And, for performance, create an index on `cp_projeto_view(projeto, id_pessoa)`.

Comment: and since the parent query isn't doing much except that having filter, you might as well eliminate the parent query and just put the having into the subquery anyways.

Comment: I try use having but the was extremely slow :(